# Unable to call a method on onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)

Tags: android, togglebutton, android-seekbar

In my application I can successfully call a method `flash_toggle_times(progress);` when toggle Button is pressed. But when I am calling same method in `public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)` It is not being called. Do not know why?

Here is complete code

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    SeekBar seekBar;
    TextView textView;
    ToggleButton toggleButton;
    boolean positionON = false;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Camera.Parameters mParams;
    boolean lightON = false;
    boolean changeIntensity = false;
    int progress = 0;
    private String TAG = "SeekBar LOG";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeVariables();
        textView.setText("Covered : " + seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax());

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // positionON = (isChecked) ? true : false;
                positionON = isChecked;
                if (isChecked) {
//Here flash_toggle_times(progress) is being called successfully
//                  flash_toggle_times(progress);

                } else {

                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void initializeVariables() {
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.m_seekbar);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m_tv);
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.m_toggle_button);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        textView.setText("Covered On Stop: " + progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax() + "\n" + changeIntensity);
        // If button is On, Turn on Light
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "StopTrackingTouch: " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(progress > 0){

//Here when this method is not being called.
            flash_toggle_times(progress);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Calling in if", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "StopTrackingTouch");




    }


    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        Log.d(TAG , "StartTrackingTouch()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {

        progress = progressValue;
//      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ProgressChanged : " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Log.d(TAG,"ProgressChanged");



    }

    public void flash_toggle_times(final int delay) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();     
        final Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);


        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Switch on the cam for app's life
                    if (mCamera == null) {
                        // Turn on Cam
                        mCamera = Camera.open();
                        try {
                            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mCamera.startPreview();
                    }

                    final int[] counter = {delay};


                    while(positionON )
                    {
                     if(counter[0] > 0){
                        toggleFlashLight();
                        sleep(counter[0]*100);
                    }
                    }

                    if (mCamera != null) {
                        mCamera.stopPreview();
                        mCamera.release();
                        mCamera = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){ 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            }
        };

        t.start();
    }

    public void turnOn(){
         if (mCamera != null) {
                // Turn on LED
                mParams = mCamera.getParameters();
                mParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                mCamera.setParameters(mParams);
         }
         lightON = true;
    }
    public void turnOff(){
        // Turn off flashlight
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mParams = mCamera.getParameters();
            if (mParams.getFlashMode().equals(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {
                mParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                mCamera.setParameters(mParams);
            }
        }
        lightON = false;
    }
    private void toggleFlashLight() {
        if (!lightON) {
            turnOn();
        } else {
            turnOff();
        }
    }

}
```